# Group JSON array data and count it if have two same value

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

Following Json needs to group by **kecamatan** to get array of **desa** along with count if kecamatan have same array value.

```
{
"data": [
        {
            "ID": 47,
            "kecamatan": "Benteng",
            "desa": "Benteng Selatan"
        },
        {
            "ID": 48,
            "kecamatan": "Benteng",
            "desa": "Benteng Selatan"
        },
        {
           "ID": 49,
            "kecamatan": "Benteng",
            "desa": "Benteng Utara"
        },
        {
            "ID": 50,
            "kecamatan": "Bontomantene",
            "desa": "Garaupa"
        }
    ]
}
```

*expected output :-*

- Benteng [Benteng selatan] = 2
- Benteng [Benteng Utara] = 1
- Bontomantene [Garaupa] = 1

Comment: what yo have tried so far?

Comment: i already parsing with volley and only add into array list

Comment: what does 2 and 1 mean ?

Comment: json array have same value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this

```
private void jsonObject() {
    String result =  "{\"data\": [{\"ID\": 47,\"kecamatan\": \"Benteng\",\"desa\": \"Benteng Selatan\"},{\"ID\": 48,\"kecamatan\": \"Benteng\",\"desa\": \"Benteng Selatan\"},{\"ID\": 49,\"kecamatan\": \"Benteng\",\"desa\": \"Benteng Utara\" },{\"ID\": 50,\"kecamatan\": \"Bontomantene\",\"desa\": \"Garaupa\"}]}";
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
        HashMap<String,Integer> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i=0;i<jsonObject.getJSONArray("data").length();i++){
            JSONObject innerJsonObject = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data").getJSONObject(i);
            String key = innerJsonObject.getString("kecamatan")+" ["+innerJsonObject.getString("desa")+"]";
            if(hashMap.containsKey(key)){
                int count = hashMap.get(key)+1;
                hashMap.put(key,count);
            }else {
                hashMap.put(key,1);
            }
        }
        Log.e("Hashmap---",hashMap.toString());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question can be considered as **"Count the number of occurrences of an element in a list grouping by fields kecamatan and desa"**.
Therefore, if you can convert the given JSON string to a list of object such as a `List<Data>`, then you can count the number of occurrences with `Stream` and `Lambda Expression` (since Java 8) as follows:

**POJOs**

```
class MyDatas {
    private List<MyData> data;

    //general getters and setters
}

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
class MyData {
    private String kecamatan;
    private String desa;

    public String getGroupBy() {
        return String.format("%s [%s]", this.getKecamatan(), this.getDesa());
    }

    //general getters and setters
}
```

For class `MyData`, I create a method `getGroupBy()` which return the key for grouping.

**Code snippet**

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
MyDatas myDatas = mapper.readValue(jsonStr, MyDatas.class);
Map<String, Long> counting = myDatas.getData()
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                MyData::getGroupBy, Collectors.counting()));
System.out.println(counting);
```

Use `Jackson` to convert the JSON string to POJO first, then use `Collectors.groupingBy()` to count the number of occurrences with `MyData::getGroupBy`.

**Console output**

> {Bontomantene [Garaupa]=1, Benteng [Benteng Selatan]=2, Benteng [Benteng Utara]=1}