# How to count same json object value and add in recycle view?

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I have a `JSON` data and I want to a count two the same `JSON` object value, but I don't know how to add it

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "ID": 1,
            "country": "Indonesia",
            "city": "Jakarta",
        },
        {
            "ID": 2,
            "country": "Indonesia",
            "city": "Jakarta",
        },
        {
            "ID": 3,
            "country": "Indonesia",
            "city": "Medan",
        },
        {
            "ID": 4,
            "country": "USA",
            "city": "New york",
        },
```

Output like: -

[image]

Comment: covert to List of Object and count it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Group JSON array data and count it if have two same value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58849723/group-json-array-data-and-count-it-if-have-two-same-value).

Answer (score 0):

Your question is wrong because your objects are not actually same, the value of id is different in both the objects, so it makes it different, you can check your values and compare them on that values, so in your case, you can do something like this -> obj1.country.equalsTo(obj2.cpuntry) && obj1.city.equalsTo(obj2.city) and mark it as same